# How to find connected components?

Tags: python, graph-theory, connected-components

I'm writing a function `get_connected_components` for a class `Graph`:

```
def get_connected_components(self):
    path=[]
    for i in self.graph.keys():
        q=self.graph[i]
        while q:
            print(q)
            v=q.pop(0)
            if not v in path:
                path=path+[v]
    return path
```

My graph is:

```
{0: [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)], 1: [], 2: [(2, 1)], 3: [(3, 4), (3, 5)], \
4: [(4, 3), (4, 5)], 5: [(5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 7)], 6: [(6, 8)], 7: [], \
8: [(8, 9)], 9: []}
```

where the keys are the nodes and the values are the edge. My function gives me this connected component:

```
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (2, 1), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 3), (4, 5), (5, 3), \
(5, 4), (5, 7), (6, 8), (8, 9)]
```

But I would have two different connected components, like:

```
[[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (2, 1), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 3), (4, 5), \
(5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 7)],[(6, 8), (8, 9)]]
```

I don't understand where I made the mistake.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Note that your representation include redundant information, eg. in `3: [(3, 4), (3, 5)]`. We already know that the edge is starting from 3!

Comment: Do you suggest me to change the values in the dict and put only the node connected and no the edges?

Comment: BTW instead of `for i in self.graph.keys(): q=self.graph[i]` you can `for (i, q) in self.graph.iteritems()`

Comment: How can you expect to get a result like you want? The only way that you ever modify `path` is with the statement `path = path + [v]`, which adds an edge to the list. If you want to create a list of lists of edges, then you need to have code that can make more than one list of edges, and add them to the list of list of edges...

Comment: Is there a reason you're creating your own graph? The awesome [networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/) library has a connected components algorithm built-in.

Comment: Yes I want create my own graph to improve my skills in python programming

Comment: @jterrace As a reader of this post and many others, I would always welcome new implementations even naive rather than referring to an existing package.

Comment: @Developer I always ask because a lot of times it's homework...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's simplify the graph representation:

```
myGraph = {0: [1,2,3], 1: [], 2: [1], 3: [4,5],4: [3,5], 5: [3,4,7], 6: [8], 7: [],8: [9], 9: []}
```

Here we have the function returning a dictionary whose keys are the roots and whose values are the connected components:

```
def getRoots(aNeigh):
    def findRoot(aNode,aRoot):
        while aNode != aRoot[aNode][0]:
            aNode = aRoot[aNode][0]
        return (aNode,aRoot[aNode][1])
    myRoot = {} 
    for myNode in aNeigh.keys():
        myRoot[myNode] = (myNode,0)  
    for myI in aNeigh: 
        for myJ in aNeigh[myI]: 
            (myRoot_myI,myDepthMyI) = findRoot(myI,myRoot) 
            (myRoot_myJ,myDepthMyJ) = findRoot(myJ,myRoot) 
            if myRoot_myI != myRoot_myJ: 
                myMin = myRoot_myI
                myMax = myRoot_myJ 
                if  myDepthMyI > myDepthMyJ: 
                    myMin = myRoot_myJ
                    myMax = myRoot_myI
                myRoot[myMax] = (myMax,max(myRoot[myMin][1]+1,myRoot[myMax][1]))
                myRoot[myMin] = (myRoot[myMax][0],-1) 
    myToRet = {}
    for myI in aNeigh: 
        if myRoot[myI][0] == myI:
            myToRet[myI] = []
    for myI in aNeigh: 
        myToRet[findRoot(myI,myRoot)[0]].append(myI) 
    return myToRet
```

Let's try it:

```
print getRoots(myGraph)
```

{8: [6, 8, 9], 1: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]}

Answer (score 26):

I like this algorithm:

```
def connected_components(neighbors):
    seen = set()
    def component(node):
        nodes = set([node])
        while nodes:
            node = nodes.pop()
            seen.add(node)
            nodes |= neighbors[node] - seen
            yield node
    for node in neighbors:
        if node not in seen:
            yield component(node)
```

Not only is it short and elegant, but also fast. Use it like so (Python 2.7):

```
old_graph = {
    0: [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)],
    1: [],
    2: [(2, 1)],
    3: [(3, 4), (3, 5)],
    4: [(4, 3), (4, 5)],
    5: [(5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 7)],
    6: [(6, 8)],
    7: [],
    8: [(8, 9)],
    9: []}

edges = {v for k, vs in old_graph.items() for v in vs}
graph = defaultdict(set)

for v1, v2 in edges:
    graph[v1].add(v2)
    graph[v2].add(v1)

components = []
for component in connected_components(graph):
    c = set(component)
    components.append([edge for edges in old_graph.values()
                            for edge in edges
                            if c.intersection(edge)])

print(components)
```

The result is:

```
[[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (2, 1), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 3), (4, 5), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 7)],
 [(6, 8), (8, 9)]]
```

Thanks, aparpara for spotting the bug.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it is incorrect. E.g. it gives 2 components for `{1: {2}, 2 : set(), 3: {2}}`, while the accepted answer correctly gives 1. But it can be easily fixed by making the graph bi-directional before applying the algorithm.

Comment: @aparpara: fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

The previous answer is great. Anyway, it took to me a bit to understand what was going on. So, I refactored the code in this way that is easier to read for me. I leave here the code in case someone founds it easier too (it runs in python 3.6)

```
def get_all_connected_groups(graph):
    already_seen = set()
    result = []
    for node in graph:
        if node not in already_seen:
            connected_group, already_seen = get_connected_group(node, already_seen)
            result.append(connected_group)
    return result


def get_connected_group(node, already_seen):
        result = []
        nodes = set([node])
        while nodes:
            node = nodes.pop()
            already_seen.add(node)
            nodes = nodes or graph[node] - already_seen
            result.append(node)
        return result, already_seen


graph = {
     0: {0, 1, 2, 3},
     1: set(),
     2: {1, 2},
     3: {3, 4, 5},
     4: {3, 4, 5},
     5: {3, 4, 5, 7},
     6: {6, 8},
     7: set(),
     8: {8, 9},
     9: set()}

components = get_all_connected_groups(graph)
print(components)
```

Result:

```
Out[0]: [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7], [6, 8, 9]]
```

Also, I simplified the input and output. I think it's a bit more clear to print all the nodes that are in a group

Comment: "nodes = nodes or graph[node] - already_seen" should be "nodes.update(graph[node] - already_seen)"

Comment: @pandasEverywhere if graph[5] = {3, 4, 5, 8}, shouldn't we get get one connected component

Comment: I corrected the error in the line "nodes = nodes or graph[node] - already_seen"  to 'nodes.update(n for n in graph[node] if n not in already_seen)'

Answer (score 1):

If you represent the graph using an [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list), you can use this generator function (implementing [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)) to get all connected components:

```
from collections import deque

def connected_components(graph):
    seen = set()

    for root in range(len(graph)):
        if root not in seen:
            seen.add(root)
            component = []
            queue = deque([root])

            while queue:
                node = queue.popleft()
                component.append(node)
                for neighbor in graph[node]:
                    if neighbor not in seen:
                        seen.add(neighbor)
                        queue.append(neighbor)
            yield component
```

Demo:

```
graph = [
    [1, 2, 3],  # neighbors of node "0"
    [0, 2],     # neighbors of node "1"
    [0, 1],     # ...
    [0, 4, 5],
    [3, 5],
    [3, 4, 7],
    [8],
    [5],
    [9, 6],
    [8]
]

print(list(connected_components(graph)))  # [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7], [6, 8, 9]]
```