# Python 3: How to remove the odd ones in a python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

Below is the example for reference:

```
pairlist = [("A","B"),("Q","R"),("S","T"),("C","E"),("F","G"),("G","I"),("A","Y"),("B","C"),("B","D")]
```

I need to get the more interconnected values (directly or Indirectly) of tuples from this list

for Example:
Refer below list where "A" is linked with "B" in tuple("A","B") in the pairlist[0] position, and "B" is linked with "C" in pairlist[7] and so on it is interconnected indirectly in large number, where as "G" is less interconnected.

```
pairs1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "Y"] #More Interconnected indirectly

pairs2 = ["G", "F", "I"] #Less Interconnected indirectly
```

The below tuples in the list No where Interconnected with any one.

```
("Q","R"),("S","T")
```

Even though "G" is repetitive and it is not interconnected with major once, it seperately interconnected with other elements which is very less connections with others.

How to get the list as below

```
pairs = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "Y"]
```

Comment: Please explain your example in a bit more detail.

Comment: You are looking for the _largest connected component_ in a graph. Try a web search with that term and you should be able to find something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python connected components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301000/python-connected-components)

Comment: Edited with more details, could you pls refer again and share the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the package `networkx`:

```
import networkx as nx

pairlist = [("A","B"),("C","E"),("F","G"),("G","I"),("A","Y"),("B","C"),("B","D")]

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(pairlist)
for i in nx.connected_components(G):
    print(i)
# {'B', 'C', 'E', 'D', 'Y', 'A'}
# {'I', 'F', 'G'}
```

[image: Graph]

To draw the graph use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

or if you use jupyter notebook:

```
%matplotlib inline
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution...Amazing work out, you have Done great job

Comment: How to get graph or plot?

Comment: @ManjunathanVenkatesan I‘ve added infos how to draw the graph to my answer.